# $.post function in jquery repeating url for ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax request with $.post function using jquery. It's repeating the url. If I just type direct url in $.post('http://url') it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e){

                    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $('#name').val();

    var url = "'"+'<?php echo base_url();?>'+"'";   

    console.log(url);

    $.post(url,
    {
      name: name
    },
    function(data,status){
        console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
      });  
  });
```

result I am getting in console

```
  "http://localhost:8080/mysite/'localhost:8080/mysite/'"
```

Comment: check what `base_url()` returns

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost:8080/mysite/';

Comment: Prepend `//` or `http://`. If you don't, it will be regarded as a relative URL and the full base url will be prepended automatically. Btw... remove the extra `'`. Not needed. Better yet, just have `/relative_path` in the URL, instead of the full base url.

Comment: So, to show only the relevant code for the question, your entire code can be reduced to: `var url = "'"+'<?php echo base_url();?>'+"'";console.log(url);`.  Nothing to do with jquery or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get the base url:

```
window.location.host + "/"
```